# Как установить атрибуты SameSite=none и Secure для JSESSIONID cookie?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-session

Большая часть сайта статическая, расположена на `github`, но есть форма обратной связи, которая расположена на другом сервере, написана на `spring-webmvc`. Использую общую настройку кросс-доменных запросов [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Value("${allowed.origins}")
    private String allowedOrigins;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/*").allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins.split(","));
    }
}
```

В *Google Chrome* оно не работает, т. к. для сессионной куки `JSESSIONID` не установлены атрибуты `SameSite=none` и `Secure`. Браузер получает куку, пишет *error* возле неё в инструментах разработчика и обратно на сервер её не передаёт. В результате сервер не видит клиента. В *Firefox* работает, но выдает предупреждение.

На сколько мне известно, интерфейс [`HttpSession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) не позволяет добавлять дополнительные атрибуты для сессионной куки. *Или я не туда смотрю?*

Проект [Java Servlet API](https://github.com/javaee/servlet-spec) в архиве - вместо него теперь [Jakarta Servlet](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/servlet-api), но атрибуты сессионной куки `SameSite=none` и `Secure` по-прежнему не настраиваются. *Если настраиваются, то как?*

Как установить атрибуты `SameSite=none` и `Secure` для `JSESSIONID` cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать бин [`SessionRepositoryFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.html) из [Spring Session Core](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-core). Заменим стандартную сессию [`HttpSession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) на Spring [`Session`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/Session.html) - сессионная кука будет называться `SESSION`:

```
SESSION=MzdmNmIyODctZDRhNi00NDM0LTk1MTctMjAyOTI3ZjI1NmM0; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
```

Дополнительные атрибуты куки можно установить с помощью [`DefaultCookieSerializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/web/http/DefaultCookieSerializer.html). Расширим немного имплементацию [`MapSessionRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/MapSessionRepository.html), поскольку в ней не реализовано удаление просроченных сессий. Добавим собственное удаление просроченных сессий перед добавлением новых. Я думаю, что для небольшого приложения этого будет достаточно:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class WebAppConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext
                .addFilter("sessionRepositoryFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class)
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        final Map<String, Session> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        MapSessionRepository sessionRepository =
                new MapSessionRepository(sessions) {
                    @Override
                    public void save(MapSession session) {
                        sessions.entrySet().stream()
                                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().isExpired())
                                .forEach(entry -> sessions.remove(entry.getKey()));
                        super.save(session);
                    }
                };
        sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(60*5);
        return sessionRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRepositoryFilter<?> sessionRepositoryFilter(MapSessionRepository sessionRepository) {
        SessionRepositoryFilter<?> sessionRepositoryFilter =
                new SessionRepositoryFilter<>(sessionRepository);

        DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        cookieSerializer.setSameSite("None");
        cookieSerializer.setUseSecureCookie(true);

        CookieHttpSessionIdResolver cookieHttpSessionIdResolver =
                new CookieHttpSessionIdResolver();
        cookieHttpSessionIdResolver.setCookieSerializer(cookieSerializer);

        sessionRepositoryFilter.setHttpSessionIdResolver(cookieHttpSessionIdResolver);

        return sessionRepositoryFilter;
    }
}
```